# JPA. What kind of relation to use between two entities. (Can't remove record from one entity)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, mapping, entity, entity-relationship

I'm writing to you after looking for some info, but as English is nt my first language I might have missed the answer for my problem.

Description:
I have a two entities. Say one of them is User, and the other one is UsersAttributes.
**User** will look like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    //some queries
})
public class User implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<UserAttributes> attributes;

    //getters, setters, constructors, equals, hashCode..
}
```

And then there is the **UserAttributes** entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    //some queries
})
public class UserAttributes implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String Name;
    //getters, setters, constructors, equals, hashCode..
}
```

And the effect that I want to have is:
The **User** is the owning side of the relationship.
The **UserAttributes** is (I don't know if I'm calling it right) a **dictionary** - values from this entity can be user by any object of **User** entity. For e.g.

```
user1  has UserAttributes 1,2
user2  has UserAttributes 2,3
user3  has UserAttributes 1,2,3
user4  has no UserAttributes
```

(I would like the UserAttributes records to be reusable)

The code taht I've written is working well,the values between entities are assigned well, but

```
When I want to remove a record from UserAttributes I can't do it if it is already 
in possesion of some User. How to solve this, what kind of mapping I should use, 
should I used **cascade** attribute, and how to do this?
```

Comment: You should do `user.getAttributes().remove(theAttributeToRemove)`. That's all you need. You should show your code and tell us what happens precisely instead of just saying "I can't do it".

Comment: Yes that works, but that's not what I want to do.I have a simple jsf page with all the UserAttributes listed.I'm choosing an element(userAttribute) and I'm removing it with a button action. When I choose a UserAttribute that is not related to any of the  User records it work fine, but when i choose the one that already is, then I have an Exception. I would like to be able to remove those attributes without worring about User enity.I'd rather to avoid going through all the users and removing the same element for every user(I don't know if that would work,and probably would be very inefficient).

Comment: Ah, so you don't want to remove an attribute from a user. You want to **delete** an attribute that is already referenced by users. If you don't want to use SQL, then you need to find all the users having this attribute, remove the attribute from these users, then delete the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks
[JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

for comments.
I think Ive solved it by using mappedBy attribute. In UserAttributes I've added this:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="attributes")
private List<User> users;
```

And in User I didn't change anything. Now I can remove attributes "irrespectively" from User entity, and the change is propagated on all the records, and there's no exceptions.